# How to simultaneously clip a ViewGroup's children *and* its background Drawable?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas, android-drawable

I have a custom LinearLayout class which I'm using to clip all of its child Views through `Canvas#clipPath()`:

```
public class MaskedLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {

    protected Path mMaskingClip = new Path();

    (...)

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

        // Update clipping path
        mMaskingClip.reset();
        (...)
        mMaskingClip.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        int save = canvas.save();
        canvas.clipPath(mMaskingClip);
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
        canvas.restoreToCount(save);
    }
}
```

The code above works great, *but* the background `Drawable` that I've set for the same `MaskedLinearLayout` is not clipped to the path that I've defined (only its children).

How should I accomplish this? Some things that I've tried include overriding method `onDraw()` (with similar code shown in method `dispatchDraw()` above) and setting its background `Drawable` boundaries manually (`Drawable#setBounds()`), both without success.

Note that I cannot use static `Drawable`s in this layout, because the latter should be able to be resized/masked dynamically while being displayed on the screen.

Thank you in advance for any answer.

Comment: try overriding `draw(Canvas)`

Comment: Well that was fast. :\ I had never noticed the difference between `onDraw` and `draw`. It works fine now. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm playing with the same situation with onDraw() and the background just not leaving. your words saved my day why i didn't notice there is draw(Canvas)